# RestSharp version of a cURL PUT request (text/plain)

Tags: c#, rest, csv, curl, restsharp

A REST API has a method to upload contents of a *.csv* file (as plain text) using the following cURL request:

```
https://API_BASEURL/v3/DATA/contactslist/$listID/CSVData/text:plain \
-H "Content-Type: text/plain" \
--data-binary "@./test.csv"
```

Where `$listID` will be replaced by a number at the time of the request and `test.csv`, I assume, will be replaced by the content of the file. Also `API_BASEURL` is the base Url of the API which for privacy reasons I have removed here.

I am trying to convert this request to *RestSharp* to use with in my program. This will be `PUT` request. I am using the following code to make the request.

```
var request = new RestRequest(string.Format("https://API_BASEURL/v3/DATA/contactslist/{0}/CSVData/text:plain", contactListId), Method.PUT);
request.AddParameter("Content-Type", "text/plain", ParameterType.HttpHeader);
request.AddBody(fileContent);
IRestResponse response = _client.Execute(request);
```

When I run the query, I suspect that the API still thinks that I am running a request of `Xml` content type and therefore I receive the following response:

> Data Content type "text/xml" does not match URL content type
>   "text/plain"

What do you think I am doing wrong?

Comment: The curl command is a POST (add `--trace-ascii logfile.txt` to get to see a full trace), you seem to use a PUT in your converted code.

Comment: @DanielStenberg I changed the verb to POST but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I don't know why an `RestRequest` object in RestSharper only accepts `Xml` and `Json` as its RequestFormat property.

Comment: So you're pushing (PUT) some data to another API? What does that API expect? What is the signature of the method you're calling on the API?

Comment: @SteenTøttrup Unfortunately the API hasn't specified whether it's a PUT or a POST but according to a comment above and the cURL code, it should be a POST request. All I know about the signature is to use the URL mentioned above in the first line, add "text/plain" as header and then the content of the file in the body,

Comment: @SteenTøttrup Do you think it's safe if I just forget about using RestSharp in this case and use the old `HttpWebRequest` instead?